# How to find length of shortest word in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to find the shortest word in an array. I am using this code

```
function findShortestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var shortestWord = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length > shortestWord){
    shortestWord = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return shortestWord;
}
```

which actually finds the longest word. I just need to change it up to find the smallest word. I’m having trouble figuring out what to set the shortestWord variable to and how i should implement that on the if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
function findShortestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var shortestWord = strSplit[0].length;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length < shortestWord){
    shortestWord = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return shortestWord;
}
```

Just grab the first word in your list, and set that as the current "shortest length". Compare all other words to your shortest length, and update as you go. Currently this will only show you the first shortest word, and not all words of that length.

Comment: Could you explain exactly how the `strSplit[0].length` works?

Comment: strSplit[0] just gets the first element in the array (the element at index 0).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning largest number because of you if condition. Use `<` instead of `>` and initialize your return variable correctly. Posting the solution with corrections below:

```
function findShortestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var shortestWord = strSplit[0].length;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length < shortestWord){
    shortestWord = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return shortestWord;
}
```

Comment: Do let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: @faizan_khan98 strSplit is an array created by `str.split(' ')` which will separate words based on space and store them into your strSplit array. Which means that `strSplit[0]` contains the first word of the sentence and `strSplit[0].length` will give you the length of the first word. Then we iterate the array to see if any smaller length number present? If yes, then we replace the `shortestWord` variable and continue to iterate the array.